# Are there any cohesive code samples for Peter Lager's Sprites 2.1.1 library for Processing?

Tags: reference, processing, sprite, sample

I'm not an experienced programmer, and I'm having trouble piecing together [the official reference documentation.](http://www.lagers.org.uk/s4p/ref/index.html)

Does anyone have a sample (or know where to find samples) of this library in action?

I've tried invoking some of the functions to get things set up, but without an idea of how everything fits together, I'm just getting basic compiler errors that I don't know how to address.

Comment: Have you looked under Files/Examples/Sprites in Processing 4?

Comment: The package author is active on the main processing Q&A site (discourse.processing.org), so you might try asking there.